# User Permissions

Tags: users

I have created a user role ,and granted it all the necessary permissions.

However, it looks like I've missed something:

Users who are assigned this role cannot update the content. They can see the content in the content list, click "edit" and see the node edit page, but on  the "body" field with the content itself, there's an error message stating:

> **This field has been disabled because you do not have sufficient permissions to edit it.**

[image].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to also give the 'content manager' role access to use one or more of the filters (Full HTML, Filtered HTML, etc) otherwise they won't be able to edit the body

You can do that on the normal permissions page, just search for 'Filter' and you should find them

Comment: @Drupal 7 new admins doesnt have the permission to edit the text format: php-code. Thanks for your help. After that it works!